# Computing "radius" of the Intersection of a Circle and an Ellipse

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I've been stuck on the following problem for awhile now. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get a solution?

---

**Suppose $r > 0$ is a real number. The circle $x^2 + (y + 4)^2 = r^2$ has radius $r$, center $(0,-4)$, and its top just touches the origin $(0,0)$.**

**We will consider a problem involving the intersections of such circles with the ellipse $\frac {x^2}{9} + \frac {y^2}{16} = 1$, as in the diagram below:**

[image]

**Compute the value of $r$ such that the area of the intersection of the ellipse $\frac {x^2}{9} + \frac {y^2}{16} = 1$ and the circle $x^2 + (y + 4)^2 = r^2$ is exactly half the area of the ellipse.**

*Hint: The area of the ellipse $\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is $\pi ab$. It should be obvious from the diagram above that the neccessary value of $r$ is between $4$ and $5$.*

Answer (score 1):

We can start from the fact that the $ \ x-$ axis already divides the ellipse exactly in half.  So the circular arc will also do so by passing from one intersection point with the ellipse *below* the $ \ x-$ axis, ascending to cross the $ \ x-$ axis, intersecting the $ \ y-$ axis *above* the $ \ x-$ axis, then descending to pass back through the $ \ x-$ axis to meet the ellipse again at the second intersection point below the $ \ x-$ axis.  This means that we could use the "signed areas" determined by (Riemann) integration to find the circular arc of radius $ \ R \ $ which will produce a *total* signed area about the $ \ x-$ axis equal to **zero**.

[image]

The function we will be integrating is that describing the circular arc,

$$ x^2 \ + \ (y \ + \ 4)^2 \  = \ R^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(x) \ = \ -4 \ + \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ x^2} \ \ ; $$

we will wish to evaluate the positive signed area [shaded in green] and the negative signed area [in red] to determine the  radius $ \ R \ $ which will make their sum zero.  (Since the circular arc and ellipse are symmetrical about the $ \ y-$ axis, it will suffice to work with just the half to the right of the $ \ y-$ axis.)

We can call the $ \ x-$ intercept of the circular arc $ \ x_0 \ $ ; the area in green is then found from

$$ A_{+} \ = \ \ \int_0^{x_0}  -4 \ + \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ x^2} \ \ dx $$

$$ = \ \left[ \ \frac{1}{2}  x \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ x^2} \ + \ \frac{R^2}{2}  \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{R}\right ) \ - \ 4x \ \right] \vert_0^{x_0} $$

$$ = \  \frac{1}{2}  x_0 \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ x_0^2} \ + \ \frac{R^2}{2}  \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{x_0}{R}\right ) \ - \ 4x_0 \ \ ,  $$

with $ \ x_0 \ $ given simply by $ \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ x_0^2} \ = \ 4 \ \Rightarrow \ x_0 \ = \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ 16} \ $ .  This permits some further simplification to

$$ A_{+} \ = \ \frac{1}{2}  x_0 \ \sqrt{16} \ + \ \frac{R^2}{2} \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{\sqrt{R^2 \ - \ 16}}{R}\right ) \ - \ 4x_0 \ = \ \frac{R^2}{2} \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{4}{R}\right ) \ - \ 2x_0 \ \ . $$

The calculation of the area in red is a little more complicated, since the intersection of the arc and the "lower half" of the ellipse falls a bit short of $ \ x \ = \ 3 \ $  .  We may call the $ \ x-$ coordinate of that intersection point $ \ X \ $ .  The function describing the "lower" semi-ellipse is given by

$$ \ 16x^2 \ + \ 9y^2 \ = \ 144 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ g(x) \ = \ -\frac{1}{3} \ \sqrt{144 \ - \ 16x^2} \ = \ -\frac{4}{3} \ \sqrt{9 \ - \ x^2} \ \ . $$

The value of $ \ X \ $ is then found from (omitting some of the algebra)

$$ -4 \ + \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ X^2} \ = \ -\frac{4}{3} \ \sqrt{9 \ - \ X^2} $$

[squaring both sides]

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 16 \ - \ 8 \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ X^2} \ + \ R^2 \ - \ X^2 \ = \ \frac{16}{9} \ (9 \ - \ X^2) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{7}{9} X^2 \ + \ R^2 \ = \ 8 \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ X^2}  $$

[again squaring both sides]

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{49}{81}X^4 \ + \ \left( \ 64 \ + \ \frac{14}{9} R^2 \ \right) \ X^2 \ + \ ( \ R^4 \ - \ 64R^2 \ ) \ = \ 0 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ X^2 \ = \ \frac{81}{98}  \left[ \ -\left( \ 64 \ + \ \frac{14}{9} R^2 \ \right) \ + \ \frac{64}{9} \sqrt{ \ 7R^2 \ + \ 81} \  \right] \ \ . $$

[one of the quadratic's solutions may be "rejected" as it is negative]

The *absolute* area in red is then found by integrating above the circular arc on the interval $ \ (x_0 \ , \ X) \ $ and above the lower semi-ellipse over $ \ (X \ , \ 3) \ $ :

$$ A_{-} \ = \ \ \int^X_{x_0}  4 \ - \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ x^2} \ \ dx \ \ + \ \ \int_X^3 \ \frac{4}{3}  \sqrt{9 \ - \ x^2} \ \ dx $$

$$ = \ \left[ \ 4x \ - \ \frac{1}{2}  x \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ x^2} \ - \ \frac{R^2}{2} \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{R}\right )  \ \right] \vert^X_{x_0} $$
$$ + \ \ \frac{4}{3} \left[ \ \frac{1}{2}  x \ \sqrt{9 \ - \ x^2} \ + \ \frac{9}{2} \ \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{3} \right) \ \right] \vert_X^3 $$

$$ = \  4X \ - \ \frac{1}{2}  X \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ X^2} \ - \ \frac{R^2}{2} \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{X}{R}\right) \ -  \ 2x_0 \   + \ \frac{R^2}{2} \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{4}{R}\right ) $$ 
$$  + \ 3 \pi \ - \ \frac{2}{3}  X \ \sqrt{9 \ - \ X^2} \ - \ 6 \ \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{X}{3} \right)  \ \ . $$

At last, with all of this in hand, we can find the value of $ \ R \ $ for which the signed area is zero, or at which $ \ A_{+} \ = \ A_{-} \ $

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{R^2}{2} \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{4}{R}\right ) \ - \ 2x_0 $$
$$ = \ 4X \ - \ \frac{1}{2}  X \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ X^2} \ - \ \frac{R^2}{2} \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{X}{R}\right) \ -  \ 2x_0 \   + \ \frac{R^2}{2} \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{4}{R}\right ) $$
$$ + \ 3 \pi \ - \ \frac{2}{3}  X \ \sqrt{9 \ - \ X^2}  \ - \ 6 \ \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{X}{3} \right)  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 3 \pi \  + \ 4X \ - \ 6 \ \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{X}{3} \right) \ - \ \frac{1}{2} X \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ X^2} $$
$$ - \ \frac{2}{3}  X \ \sqrt{9 \ - \ X^2} \ - \ \frac{R^2}{2} \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{X}{R}\right) \ = \ 0 \ \ . \quad \mathbf{[A]} $$

$$ \ \ $$

As one might imagine, this is not going to produce a simple value for $ \ R \ $ .  However, it turns out that the terms involving $ \ x_0 \ $ cancel out and working with this equation will "converge" rapidly to a result.  By experimenting with a graphing program and making an "eyeball estimate", I chose to start with an initial "trial" value of $ \ R^2 \ = 19.5 \ $ :

X ≈ 2.9516

$$ \rightarrow \ \ 3 \pi \  + \ 4 (2.9516) \ - \ 6 \ \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{2.9516}{3} \right) \ - \ \frac{1}{2}  \cdot \ 2.9516 \cdot  \sqrt{19.5 \ - \ 2.9516^2} $$
$$ - \ \frac{2}{3} \cdot 2.9516 \cdot \sqrt{9 \ - \ 2.9516^2} \ - \ \frac{19.5}{2} \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{2.9516}{\sqrt{19.5}}\right) \ \approx \ -0.1554 \ \ .  $$

Since the cancellation used to produce equation **A** above was essentially the result of subtracting terms to write $ \ A_{-} \ - \ A_{+} \ = \ 0 \ $ , a negative value here means that the positive signed area is slightly too large.  If we take $ \ R^2 \ = \ 19.0 \ $ as our second estimate, we obtain

$$ X \ \approx \ 2.9419 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ A_{-} \ - \ A_{+} \ \approx \ +0.0287 \ \ . $$

We can now interpolate a value of $ \ R^2 \ = \ 19.08 \ $ between the first two estimates to produce a fairly precise solution:

$$ X \ \approx \ 2.943501 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ A_{-} \ - \ A_{+} \ \approx \ -0.00088 \ \ . $$

So it appears that a good estimate for the radius of the dividing circle is $ \ R \ \approx \ 4.368 \ $ .  (I should be very surprised if the exact value were an algebraic number...)